# Working with two ROS Versions on single system

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I would like to install two versions of ROS --> Groovy and Hydro (or Groovy and Fuerte for example). Is it fine to work this way or should I have only one version of ROS installed? Has anyone tried this before?

Thanks
Murali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103116/working-with-two-ros-versions-on-single-system/) by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 246 on 2013-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes this is possible. If you install from e.g. Ubuntu packages they will install into /opt/ros/groovy and opt/ros/hydro.

Then you simply source the setup.bash file from the distribution you want to use.

NB: Be careful not to mix up the versions when you are running your robot. Sometimes it works, but other times it gives you some strange behaviour.

---

Originally posted by [Karl Damkjær Hansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2205/karl-damkj%C3%A6r-hansen/) with karma: 139 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on 2013-11-20**:
Thank you Karl, I am trying to install groovy, hydro and fuerte. your answer is right. Will try experimenting...
regards
Murali